# Python com Windows Form ou interface gráfica

Tags: python, windows

Olá, sou iniciante em Python 2.7 e estou querendo saber como aplico interface gráfica em aplicações desenvolvidas com Python, assim como o html faz a interface para o php e o visual studio é usado para fazer os windows form em c#, mas e python como funciona isso?

Comment: Recomendo trabalhar com o construtor de Inteface gráfica Glade. É uma ótima ferramenta pois você modela seu programa através da construção visual. O glade gera um xml que é facilmente comunicável com o Python.
Se quiser saber um pouco mais o site é este do download:
<https://glade.gnome.org/>

Comment: Gtk é mais uma ferramenta gráfica para python http://www.pygtk.org/

Comment: Pablo, se você trabalha com o Glade, então mande exemplos. Por que a documentação lá é horrível! Tutorial não abre e redireciona para outros links. O Inglês é até bem "facinho", mas em termos de documentação, é ruim. Eu até gostaria muito de usar o Glade se ele fosse realmente bom (bem documentado) para aprender bem como fazer. Só que, para quem quer iniciar, no uso da criação de GUIs, não serve. A propagando é bonita, mas na prática, não funciona.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O Python trabalha com diversos toolkits para interfaces gráficas, como Gtk, Qt e wx, mas o toolkit padrão é o Tkinter.

Um exemplo básico que você pode experimentar:

```
from Tkinter import *

def Cumprimente():
    hello.set("Olá, você!")

gui = Tk()

gui.title("Py5 - Python + Tkinter")
gui.geometry("400x300")

btn = Button(gui, text="Cumprimente", command=Cumprimente)
btn.pack()

hello = StringVar()
lbl = Label(gui, textvariable=hello)
lbl.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Pode salvar isso como um arquivo qualquer de extensão ".py" no Idle e executar através dele mesmo (F5).

Comment: showwww vlwwwwwwww

Comment: @Cachuera, que bom que foi útil. Seja bem-vindo e, por favor, sinalize as respostas que solucionam o seu problema como respondidas, ok? :)

Comment: como sinalizo??

Comment: Existe uma marca cinza abaixo da seta apontando para baixo na resposta. Ela fica verde quando você clica.